# Using Jquery Toggle show & hide, but gets weird floating

Tags: jquery, css-float

I have no clue how to solve this or what to even look at, I use floating for a bunch of classes and it works great. Also on top of that I made so you can click to show and hide content (inside the class to show the content). My problem, float is just acting weird when the classes are expanding. Because when you click them.
I was close to launch my new created page but then I saw this! See it in action:

[click here to see my page](http://epicesports.com/buildorders.php#protoss)
Click on the "box" to the right where it says: "Forge Nexus Opening" and see that my bottom "box" (with text saying: "Nexus Forge Opening") is getting putted down and follows with the other box and leaves a gap. How do  I solve this issue? I dont want white space between the boxes.

Jquery used for this.

```
$(".desccontent").show();
$(".desccontent").hide();  

    $('.buildorderbox').click(function(){
    $(this).children(".desccontent").slideToggle();
    });
```

Each class element got float: left and auto height. Any ideas?

Comment: What browser are you using? I couldn't find where to click!!! be more specific!!!

Comment: I am using Chrome and Firefox 15.0.1 both gives same result. I updated my post. I am so sorry that I can't explain so good. Thanks for not being so mean so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two different divs, create one for left and another for right content

```
<div id="protoss">
  <div class="columnLeft" style="width: 350px; float:left">
    <div class="buildorderbox"></div>
    <div class="buildorderbox"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="columnRight" style="width: 350px; float:left">
    <div class="buildorderbox"></div>
    <div class="buildorderbox"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is a very good solution!! It's a shame I can only thank you in digital form!

Comment: I will look into this because I am fetching data from a mysql database and using while (php) to type out the same class with the information in it but I find a way to fix it!